# update table based on a sub query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

sample data [image]

I have a query

```
SET @Query2 =
    'SELECT * FROM My_tbl WHERE '+ @Condition2
```

that retrieves data from table "My_tbl" based on certain conditions as laid by @Conditions5

```
DECLARE @Condition5 NVARCHAR(255) =(
            SELECT * WHERE Field1 IS NOT NULL AND FIELD2 IS NOT NULL);
```

Is it possible to update 'My_tbl' table in such a way that it gets updated and only holds the data values after executing the @Query2?

something like: (Wrong code!) want to get your views, please...

```
UPDATE my_tbl 
SET my_tbl = 'SELECT * FROM My_tbl WHERE '+ @Condition2
```

Comment: Sample data and expected output are really going to help here. I'm really struggling to understand what you're after here.

Comment: Try doing a `DROP TABLE` and a `SELECT INTO`.

Comment: @EzLo If I would Drop my_tbl, then my Query2 will not work...

Comment: Oh, then maybe you need to do a `DELETE` when your condition **isn't** met.

Comment: @EzLo Can you share some code snippet, please? would be easier to follow... Thanks

Comment: Instead of `'SELECT * FROM My_tbl WHERE '+ @Condition2`, try doing `'DELETE T FROM My_tbl AS T WHERE NOT( ' + Condition2 + ')'`

Comment: @EzLo It was a very handy approach. Thanks.